# fetch api call blocked by cors

Tags: jquery, spring, fetch-api

I have a spring server running and from watching tutoirals tutorials i am made a simple function

```
registerUser() {

user = {
  firstname: this.firstname,
  lastname: this.lastname,
  email: this.email,
  //more fields
}

var h = new Headers({"Content-Type":"application/json"});,
fetch('/user', {method: "POST", headers: h, body: JSON.stringify(user)})
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(error => console,error("Error:", error))

}
```

But whenever I run above script in HTML through $(function() {.. I get an error saying

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '<...>' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross-Origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes. http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

I searched for error and it looks to me my spring app is not running at HTTP, but when I check the browser and try `http://localhost:8080/test` it is working fine with the request received on the server log.

My spring controller has

```
@PostMapping("/user")
@CrossOrigin("*")
public void createUser(@RequestBody User user){}
```

I enabled all origins with * why it is still blocked by cors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the tutorial you followed likely has those static resources served by the Spring app. Your calling script doesn't have the same origin as `http://localhost:8080`, so do

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/user'...)
```

Comment: it was doing file://C:...i don't understand why it does no http by default